# Mongoose error: Property 'Buffer' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am facing an issue that the mongoose returns an error likes
`node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts:1867:33 - error TS2339: Property 'Buffer' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'.`

My NestJS is running properly under my development machine with below specification

```
Node version: v14.17.3
```

Base image when packaging docker image

```
Node version: v14.17.1
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.1"
  }
}
```

I found a few solution like adding `@types/node` but it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Go to package.json file.
Change
**@types/node: "^16.0.0" to @types/node: "^15.6.1"**
and save it.

Then run npm install !!

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It was unexpectedly install @types/node by DevOps team. So it was the build file issue, not the dependencies issue. I will close this question.